# Centering Launch Screen in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, launch

I set up a Launch Screen in xcode with Inferred Size, Simulated Size: Fixed. I put a View in it that covers the whole View Controller. In that View is an image and a label. Both the image and label have height and width constraints, in addition to constraints centering both items with the superview center, yet somehow whenever I run the simulation the label is centered on the screen but the image is off to the right. Anyone know what I need to fix here? Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Edit: It turns out I had a previous launch screen file listed in Info.plist. I updated it with the new launch screen file name and it worked. I also changed the launch screen to remove the splash.

Comment: What about the container view's constraint? Have you set them as leading+trainling+top+bottom or what?

Comment: The container view doesn't have any constraints. If I select the view and "Pin", it's all greyed out. There's a "Top Layout Guide" and a "Bottom Layout Guide" and that's it.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of your Launch screen with it's view hierarchy.

Comment: Added a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951817/launch-screen-storyboard-with-centered-image-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use width and height equal to, and align your view horizontally in the container..

Also, as per Apple's human guidelines they advise against having a splash screen.

Comment: Haha well then I guess it's moot. Thanks!

Comment: Its unnecessary to have a splash screen. Just have your launchscreen blank with background color the same as your first view controller's.

Comment: I guess I'll have to come up with a background color then lol. Thanks!

Comment: I could've sworn apple was requiring splash screen not more than 2-3 years ago; did they reverse this advice?

Answer (score -1):

Workaround of this issue is to not place image vertically centered. You can move image a bit to top or bottom. In such way issue won't be visible.

Comment: This may work, but it's only a workaround for something that is actually possible without having to compromise on the design in this way.