# React-Native I keep getting "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5" but I have the correct images?

Tags: ios, react-native

I keep getting "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5,  New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}" but I have the correct images, really not sure what is going on here.

Here are my images

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding a storyboard as the LaunchScreen.

Follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/37952587/3946689

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by deleting everything and reading all the images. It seems if you have duplicates it creates this issue